# Django/Jquery inlineformset: why add-row button is hidden when using max_num option i my formset?

Tags: jquery, django, inline-formset

I am developping a Django project and I use nested inlineformset with jQuery to get add-row and delete-row buttons.

It works but I would like to use inlineformset options extra=3 and max_num=4.

The problem is that, with max_num option, the add-row button is hidden (as I can see in developer tool).
I don't understand why.
My first attempt was to display the button using JQuery (display=False -> display=True).
The button is displayed but when I click it add a row the button disappeared...

It should have a better way to do that...

---

EDIT

I've read https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js#L49 to better understand how it works

I try to set **addContainerClass: 'addButton'**, **hideAddButton: false** or 'force' add button to be displayed (**addButton.show()**) but none of these works...

forms.py

```
NAME = Thesaurus.options_list(2,'fr')
ACCESS = Thesaurus.options_list(3,'fr') 
ApplicationFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    UtilisateurProjet, Application, #Utilisateur, Application,
    fields=('app_app_nom','app_dro'),
    widgets={
        'app_app_nom': forms.Select(choices=NAME),
        'app_dro': forms.Select(choices=ACCESS)
    },
    extra=3,
    can_delete=True,
    max_num=4,
)
```

js

```
<script src="{% static 'project/js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>

<script>
    $('.link-formset').formset({
        addText: 'Ajouter',
        deleteText: 'Supprimer',
        prefix: '{{ application.prefix }}'
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: no I didn't find a solution for now